# sql - select all values id's and count how many time they appear within the last month

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT i.name, x.total FROM Item i, 
(SELECT Item_id, COUNT(Item_id) as total FROM Tracking 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) GROUP BY Item_id)x 
WHERE i.id = x.Item_id
```

what I want is to count how many times a resource is used in the last month
example- (item 1, 0),
         (item 2, 4),
         (item 3, 2)
what I get is only the items that have a value, so item 1 will not show and any other items that don't appear in the last month

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I would try GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: You need to left join ALL the items with date-filtered `Tracking` rows.

Comment: Use a left join instead of a subselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT     i.name, x.total 
FROM       Item i
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT   Item_id, COUNT(Item_id) as total 
            FROM     Tracking 
            WHERE    date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
            GROUP BY Item_id) x ON i.id = x.Item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all* items, regardless of whether they had any appearances, then use conditional aggregation instead of a `where` clause:

```
SELECT Item_id,
       SUM(date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as total
FROM Tracking 
GROUP BY Item_id;
```